# Two-Sided Matching in R (without Java)

Tags: java, r

I need to run a two-sided matching algorithm to place fellows with host offices (essentially the hospital/residents problem or the college admissions problem). The R package matchingMarkets would be perfect but due to security issues my IT department will not allow installation of a Java developer onto my work computer. Is there a workaround or another R package that can do two-sided matching without the use of Java or C++?

Comment: What do you mean by “java developer”? You say “due to security issues my IT department will not allow installation of a Java developer onto my work computer” … but it seems unlikely that IT wouldn’t allow installing Java when they allow e.g. R (not impossible, but unlikely, and slightly incompetent on their part).

Comment: Specifically the package calls for Java JDK8. IT will not allow me to download development tools full stop (trust me, I tried). That is why I'm reaching out here.

Answer (score 1):

The [*Optimisation* CRAN task view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html) lists another package, [‘matchingR’](https://cran.r-project.org/package=matchingR), that performs two-sided matching. Give it a shot.